# Remove a specific string value from the whole dataframe without specifying the column or row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has some cells with the value of "?". now this value causes an error ("Could not convert string to float: "?") whenever i try to use the multi information metric.

I already found a solution by simply using:

```
df.replace("?",0,inplace=True)
```

And it worked. BUT i'm wondering if i wanted to remove the whole row if one of its cells has the value of "?", how can i do that?

Notice that i don't have the column names that contains this value. it's spread in different column and that's why i can't use `df.drop`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for each cell if they are equal to `"?"` and then get a boolean series over rows that contain that character in *any* one of their cells. Then get the indices of rows that gave `True` and drop them:

```
has_ques_mark = df.eq("?").any(axis=1)            # a boolean series
inds = has_ques_mark[has_ques_mark].index         # row indices where above is True

new_df = df.drop(inds)
```

Comment: It worked just fine and it's also simple. Many thanks Mustafa

Comment: @Mohamed_Fergany glad to be of help!  If you wish, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['column_name'] == "?"].index, inplace=True)
```

or in a slightly simpler syntax but maybe a bit less performant:

```
df = df.loc[df['column_name'] != "?"]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing sophros. but i'm afraid you didn't notice the last part in my question about  not knowing the column names. Anyway i tried the method in the above commend and it worked.                                                                                                                  
Thanks again :)

Comment: Indeed, I have not.